# Laravel Interface Iterator not found

Tags: laravel, iterator

Laravel is giving me the following error message:

```
"Interface App\Libraries\Iterator" not found.
```

This is my code:

```
class Combinations Implements Iterator
{
...
}
```

What can I do to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

That isn't a Laravel interface, it's a PHP one.  It also resides in the global namespace.  Try the following...

```
class Combinations implements \Iterator {

}
```

Comment: Or the alternative option, `use Iterator;` at the top of the file.